# Wrap elements all the way around a specific element with only CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to get elements to wrap to both sides of a floated element, as opposed to just on one side. For example, I have http://jsfiddle.net/p384K/. I want the elements to be able to dynamically exist on the left-hand side of `#main` as well as the right-hand side. Can I do this with purely CSS?

Comment: The only way I can think of is a container for both sides, something along the lines of this http://jsfiddle.net/sXD4c/

Answer (score 2):

There is really no easy way to achieve what you wish to do, unfortunately. It can be achieved with some hacking and assuming you already know the size of your central element. The technique would be basically **to make space** for the central element **inside your side elements**.

A very detailed description of such a procedure for complicated shapes can be found in this 2005 ALA article: [**Cross-Column Pull-Out Part Two: Custom Silhouettes**](http://alistapart.com/article/crosscolumn2).

I have put up two basic examples of what you can do.

### Example 1: using a `.space` element

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ajuqef/2)</kbd>

What you do is having an HTML structure such as this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="center"></div>
    <div class="left">
        <div class="space></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right>
        <div class="space></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You have the main page container whose role is to set up the global width, perhaps center the content and **have `position: relative`**.

Then your CSS:

```
.container {

  position:  relative;
  width:     600px;

}

.left, .right {

  width:      50%;

}

.left { float: left; }

.right { float: right; }

.center {

  margin-left:      -75px; // Negative half the width
  width:            150px;
  height:           600px;
  position:         absolute;
  left:             50%;

}

.right .space { float: left;  }
.left  .space { float: right; }
```

Basically, what you are doing is creating a `.center`-sized hole, equally partitioned between your `.left` and `.right` columns, then absolutely positioning the element inside that hole.

### Example 2: using pseudo-elements

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ajuqef/4)</kbd>

Same approach, but instead of using an additional HTML element, you use the `::before` pseudo-elements of your column to make a hole inside them. The only change in the CSS would be:

```
.left::before, .right::before {

  content: "";
  height: 600px;
  width:  75px;

}

.left::before { float: right; }

.right::before { float: left; }
```

This makes a simple two side-columns + one center-column layout viable. But you might need to add additional elements depending on how complicated your layout is, as described in the ALA article.

The catch is, as I have mentioned above, that you have to know the size of the center element to make this work. If you are willing to add a tad of JS, you could easily solve this problem by calculating dynamically the size and resize the hole accordingly.

There might be some other CSS-only approaches which are more efficient than this, but there is no native way to get elements wrap on both sides of another element, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: The issue is that I'll be pulling in elements dynamically, and don't want to use a column layout. I just didn't know if it was even possible. I'm using jQuery Isotope, and building off of jQuery Masonry. I appreciate the answer, but not quite what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Mmm… not sure if I understand the issue. If you're pulling them via jQuery, why not positioning them via jQuery? If you could be more specific with a better example (or perhaps a fiddle), perhaps I could try to help you more :)